# Can I use wilcoxon rank sum test if no assumptions are met and observations are dependent?

Tags: r, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a data set of parking and reservation transactions. I want to analyze if there is a significant change in the transactions after pricing changes have taken place on a certain date. I thought to do this I will split the data set into two groups. Those transactions that have taken place before the pricing change and those after the pricing change. The time period is the same for both groups. I thought that I would simply use a t-test and compare the means of the revenue of both groups to see if they are significantly different. However, looking at my data set I see that my data has the following characteristics:

- There are outliers in both groups
- The assumption of normality is not met.
- The assumption of equal variances is not met.
- The samples I believe are dependent because it is possible that the same users made transactions in both periods. However here is the catch, not all users are paired for both groups. What I mean is there are users who are in both groups and users who are only in one group.

After discovering this I thought I must use a Wilcoxon test. Specifically, the Wilcoxon rank-sum test however what I seemed to be reading is that this test has one assumption that the distributions of the groups have to be symmetric. So no skews. I got this knowledge from [here](https://bolt.mph.ufl.edu/6050-6052/unit-4b/module-13/details-for-non-parametric-alternatives/#:%7E:text=The%20Wilcoxon%20rank%2Dsum%20test,the%20assumptions%20are%20not%20met.)

**Question**

Should I still use a Wilcoxon ranked sum test although not all observations are paired in both groups? As I write this I think the answer is no but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to transform the data that would make the observations independent? My initial guess is no.

**Edit**
So to answer a few questions about the users. If I wanted I could combine a column to my dataset of user ids and with that column I could know which transactions come from which users.

However, it is possible the in the group of transactions that took place after the pricing change that there are new users who were not in the previous period. Also, there can be users in the previous period who are not in the new period.
The number of transactions as well in both groups is different.

The groups as well are not small.

Comment: WRS assumes independence.  If you're looking for advice on a test, then it would be better to supply more details of your data.

Comment: I suggest to make a graph with group 1 on the left and group 2 on the right, connecting transactions belonging to the same user by a line. Equal variances and even more so dependence might be an issue, but might turn out to be negligible looking at the data.

Comment: Do you know which user made which transaction?

Comment: I will edit my question to supply more information. I do have a user id column so it is possible to know which user made which transaction.

Comment: @Lewian I'm not exactly sure what you mean by your suggestion. Does this type of graph have a name so that I can look it up? Do you mean that on the left I have an observation for each user and the amount of transactions they have done for the first period and then connect that to the second period? Also, how can I tell by looking at the data if the assumptions turn out to be negligible?

Comment: @Nick: I don't know whether it has a specific name, but the left side graphs here... https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/statistics/stat_graphing_results_paired_t.htm ... are of such a kind. I find it hard to explain how to see things without actually seeing them myself. Sometimes something clearly jumps to the eye. As there are several assumptions of interest, there are several things to look out for. I'm not even sure whether all you have is matched pairs or whether some pairs are connected and other observations are unconnected.